# How can I simply remove the .php extension using .htaccess only for a specific file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have seen quite a few answers on how to redirect many URLs so that any .php extensions are removed, but this has been causing some troubles for me with conflicts.

```
RewriteRule ^quote/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^quote/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

I already am redirecting `/quotes/1` `/quotes/2` etc to `/index.php?id=1` and `/index.php?id=2` etc. But what I really want to do is simply match `/random/` and have it point to `/random.php` and none of the existing answers seem to be that specific.

Thanks.

Comment: So you handle all of your business logic in `index.php` like if `isset($_GET['id']){...}`? Well, what you really should focus on now is to any popular php framework. This is a very basic thing called **Routing and Controllers**

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `.php` extension with `.htaccess` use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well for `/random` however is there any way to get it working for `/random/` with the trailing slash as well?

Comment: @Rizier123 don't you want to capture anything for `$1` to work? And it is a good idea to add check for the directory `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`